# is it possible to specify a cache with fragment caching or determine cache hit / miss ratio for a specific call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached

We have a Rails 4.2 app and are currently using a shared cache across several apps. Our memcached miss rate is pretty high (like 85% hits and 15% misses) but this is complicated by the fact that multiple apps are sharing the same memcached instance. So we might be getting a high miss rate for a couple of critical cache processes (our DataDog data would support this).

Is it possible to specify a cache store on a fragement cache call like:

```
cache(order, OrderCache) do
  # whatever
end
```

I think this is possible with object caching by doing something like:

```
OrderCache =  ActiveSupport::Cache::MemCacheStore.new
```

Would there be other ways to untangle the hit / miss ratio of specific cache actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's a complicated idea but I think you can make your own cache store wrapper that decides which cache store to use if I understand your question correctly.

When calling the cache method, it eventually calls `read_fragment` and `write_fragment` on your controller https://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Caching/Fragments/read_fragment and those methods call `cache_store.read` and `cache_store.write`.

Then you could have a custom cache store class with custom `read` and `write` method that, depending on an option, delegates the read and write to real cache stores.

```rb
class MyCacheStore < ...
  def initialize
    @my_catchall_store = ActiveSupport::Cache::MemCacheStore.new
    @my_order_store = ActiveSupport::Cache::MemCacheStore.new
  end

  def read(key, options)
    case options[:store]
    when :order_store then @my_order_store.read(key, options)
    else
      @my_catchall_store.read(key, options)
    end
  end

  # similar for .write
```

Then you use it like...

```rb
cache(:order, store: :order_store) do
  # some code
end

cache(:something_else) do
  # some code
end
```

I'm not sure if that's what you are asking sorry.